# Is 'where' accurate here, or is 'with' accurate?

Tags: mathematics, where

I wrote in my  manuscript:
'Let *f* be a *k*-face of D where $k \ge 4$.'

However, I feel that replacing 'where' with 'with' might be more appropriate. I'm a bit uncertain, so I'm posing this question. Can both be used, or is there a strict distinction between the two?

P.S.: Unlike the math SE and some others, this site appears not to support LaTeX; please note that $k \ge 4$ indicates that *k* is greater than or equal to 4.

Comment: "Let *f* be a *k*-face of D where *k* ≥ 4"

Comment: This is a matter of style.  I suspect both convey a similar meaning and will be understood.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because math has its own formats.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Are you referring to LaTeX, or are you talking about English styles? The focus here is not on LaTeX.

Comment: The question is not a matter of proper English, but what is standard in technical formulas. This site doesn't handle those issues.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Thank you. This is not quite what I had in mind. I thought that any English-related questions could be discussed.

Comment: This is not a discussion site per se. If a format in a specialized field accepts *unbold, no-log, delist, ping, zap, and "let A=A+1,"* that's the way to go. It does not make them good English across the board.

Comment: A reasonable way to decide whether a question (including a question about language usage) is too niche for ELU is 'Would this help/interest/be answerable by a greater number of people on ELU or on say Mathematics.SE?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either *where* or *with* is fine in your sentence, as would be *for*. Here the function of the prepositional phrase is merely to restrict the **values** that *k* may take, and that restriction applies in the **definition** of *f*. Indeed, *k* is introduced merely to serve in defining *f*.

A context in which there would be a preference among these three prepositions is in phrases that explain variables’ **semantics**, which conventionally use *where*. Thus,

> The more general form of Newton’s second law of motion, the form that must be used to obtain the force *F* involved in changing the motion of a body of non-constant mass, is
>
> *F* = *d**p***/*dt*,
>
> **where** the vector ***p*** is the body’s momentum.